# setInterval doesnt wait internal time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know what is the problem here, setInterval doesnt wait interval time i set it to wait. First it waits it but after that it keeps doing that x times ms
And this code is in react.js render

```
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log("moi")
        }, 4000)
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{}</h1>
                <h1></h1>
                <button><h1>Paina</h1></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: [Have you checked out the documentation for `setInterval()`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: The only thing that will be delayed is the function passed to set interval. In this case, `console.log` will be the only thing delayed.

Comment: I'm looking to run that function every 4 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing set a `setInterval` inside of your render, you will creating more instances of this than you bargained for. If you're using classes, place this inside of your `constructor()`.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  // You may want to assign this to a variable so you can stop it if need be
  setInterval(() => console.log("moi"), 4000);
}

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <h1></h1>
      <h1></h1>
      <button><h1>Paina</h1></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```